# Scroll event that slides div out of view port with Jquery - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have the hero section slide up out of the view port when the user scrolls once. The default state of the page has the scroll-bar hidden, but i'd like a scroll-bar within the .content-section.

I found a website that does exactly what i'm looking for http://www.ryanedy.com/

Here is what I've tried so far... [Code Pen Here](https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/eRQevy)

```
//1. User scrolls
$(document).one("scroll", function() {
  $(".website-wrapper").animate({
  bottom: "1000",  
  opacity: 0.25,

  },300,function(){

  });
});
```

Comment: Here is a combined version of both answers i received. Thanks a bunch for the help. 

https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/VWqYvY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the effect the site is applying `translate3d(0, 100%, 0)` on the content section which transforms it off the screen.

The event handler sets the transform to `translate3d(0, 0%, 0)` to transform it back on the screen.

To animate the style change transition is used `transition: all 0.7s ease;`

Since the content is set to 100% height and there are no scroll bars, it is actually a click handler that triggers the animation.

```js
//1. User clicks the element
$('.website-wrapper').click(function() {
    $(".content-section").css("-webkit-transform","translate3d(0, 0%, 0)");
    $(".content-section").css("-ms-transform","translate3d(0, 0%, 0)");
    $(".content-section").css("transform","translate3d(0, 0%, 0)");
});
//2. Height of Hero-Section goes to 0px with a transform.
```

```css
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.hero-section {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
}
.content-section {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="website-wrapper">
  <div class="hero-section"><h1>Hero Section</h1></div>
  <div class="content-section"><h1>Content Section</h1></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sens, and it seems so simple now.  Do you know how i can have the scroll-bar only show within .content-section?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of your javascript try this instead

```
$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function() {
  $(".hero-section").slideUp(2000, function (){
     $("body").css('overflow','scroll');
  });
});
```

[**Try it**](https://codepen.io/moneer99/pen/EXORBb)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've already tried the .hide function. I do like the fade effect, but i prefer the section to slide up out of view then fade or at the same time like my example.

Comment: I just saw your updated answer. This is much closer to what i was thinking. I assume it is sliding up out of sight because the body has overflow:hidden?

How would i slow the slide up affect so you can actually see it slide up?

Comment: control the delay with millisecond .. I made it 2000 now please check

Comment: You can try in on the snippet as well

Comment: Thanks so much. That's great. I ended up combining both the answers from you and Alexander Higgins. https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/VWqYvY